# Find index of array in multidimensional array by string value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I need the index of an array in a multidimensional array if it contains a unique string.

array:

```
[
    {:id=>5, :name=>"Leaf Green", :hex_value=>"047115"},
    {:id=>15, :name=>"Lemon Yellow", :hex_value=>"FFF600"},
    {:id=>16, :name=>"Navy", :hex_value=>"285974"}
]
```

If hex_value of 'FFF600' exists, return the arrays position, which in this case would be 1.

This is where I am at, but it's returning [].

```
index = array.each_index.select{|i| array[i] == '#FFF600'}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's returning `nil`, because there's no element `i` (index) in the array with value `#FFF600` (nor `FFF600`), you need to access to the `hex_value` key value:

```
p [
  {:id=>5, :name=>"Leaf Green", :hex_value=>"047115"},
  {:id=>15, :name=>"Lemon Yellow", :hex_value=>"FFF600"},
  {:id=>16, :name=>"Navy", :hex_value=>"285974"}
].yield_self { |this| this.each_index.select { |index| this[index][:hex_value] == 'FFF600' } }
# [1]
```

Giving you `[1]`, because of using `select`, if you want just the first occurrence, you can use `find` instead.

I'm using `yield_self` there, to avoid assigning the array to a variable. Which is equivalent to:

```
array = [
  {:id=>5, :name=>"Leaf Green", :hex_value=>"047115"},
  {:id=>15, :name=>"Lemon Yellow", :hex_value=>"FFF600"},
  {:id=>16, :name=>"Navy", :hex_value=>"285974"}
]
p array.each_index.select { |index| array[index][:hex_value] == 'FFF600' }
# [1]
```

---

Being Ruby, you can use the method for that: [`Enumerable#find_index`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-find_index)

```
p [
  {:id=>5, :name=>"Leaf Green", :hex_value=>"047115"},
  {:id=>15, :name=>"Lemon Yellow", :hex_value=>"FFF600"},
  {:id=>16, :name=>"Navy", :hex_value=>"285974"}
].find_index { |hash| hash[:hex_value] == 'FFF600' }
# 1
```

Comment: #2 and #3 are appropriate, but I find a #1 a bit bizarre. Presumably the array has been computed or has been given as an argument to a method (not a literal), so it must already be assigned to a variable. Upvoted, but I wouldn't be displeased if you ditched #1. :-)